# How to find the inverse Fourier transfmation of $\exp(-sk)/k$.

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

I've tried this with the help of hint given by one of my friend.He told me to first find the Inverse fourier transformation of $\exp(-sk)$ which is 
$$ \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt \pi}\frac{x}{x^2+ s^2}$$
After this I proceed by applying integration by parts, but I'm not getting the desired result
which is $$\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt \pi}  \arctan \left( \frac{x}{s} \right)$$ 
Please help me .I've invested lots of time in this.

Any kind of Hints are welcome.

Comment: It doesn't have a Fourier Transform.  The integral diverges exponentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ as

$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}\,dx$$

Then, the inverse Fourier Transform of $F(k)$ is given by

$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k) e^{ikx}\,dk$$

We seek to find the inverse Fourier Transform for $F(k)=\frac{e^{-s|k|}}{k}$ where $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and $s>0$.
________________________________________________________-
**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

We interpret the inverse Fourier Transform as the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac1{2\pi}\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-s|k|}}{k} e^{ikx}\,dk \tag 1\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-sk}}{k} \sin(kx)\,dk \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \left(\int_s^\infty e^{-s'k}\,ds'\right) \sin(kx)\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\pi}\int_s^\infty \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-s'k} \sin(kx)\,dk \,ds'\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\pi}\int_s^\infty \frac{x}{s'^2+x^2}\,ds'\\\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\text{sgn}(x)-\frac{i}{\pi}\arctan(s/x)\\\\
&=\frac{i}{\pi}\arctan(x/s) \tag 3
\end{align}$$
________________________________________________________-
**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

The inverse Fourier Transform of $G(k)=e^{-s|k|}$ for $s\in \mathbb{R}$ with $s>0$ is

$$\begin{align}
g(x)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-s|k|}e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{(s+ix)k}\,dk+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(-s+ix)k}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{s+ix}+\frac{1}{s-ix}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2s}{s^2+x^2}
\end{align}$$

Note that $g(x)=-i\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ where $f(x)$ is given by $(1)$.  Noting from $(2)$ that $f(0)=0$, we find that

$$f(x)=i\int_0^x g(x')\,dx'=\frac{i}{\pi}\arctan(x/s)$$

which agrees with the result in $(3)$.

Comment: :thanks,will you please help in finding inverse fourier sine transformation of the same function.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The sine transform is identical to this answer divided by $i$ since the cosine component integrates to $0$ in the principal value sense.